# How To Retrieve Column's Data of a Table, Store It Into An Array, and Finally Echo The Array

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

Here's what I'm basically trying to do:

1. Retrieve the values of a column
2. Store those values into an array in PHP
3. Echo each value with a line break in between each value

Here's my attempted code:

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "bruhfrogzombie098", "growtapi_social");

if (!$connection) {
die("Failed to connect to MYSQL: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
};

$members = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Username FROM s_users");

$members_status = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Status_Content FROM s_users");

$members_array = array();
while ($member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($members)) {
$members_array[] = $member;
};

$members_status_array = array();
while ($status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($members_status)) {
$members_status_array[] = $status;
};


?>
```

And this is where I want to echo out the values:

```
<center>
        <h1>Members Directory</h1>
        <div style="width: 20%; height; 75%; border: 3px solid black; margin: auto; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;">
            <?php echo $members_array['$member'];
                  echo "<br />";
            ?>
        </div>
</center>
```

I don't receive any errors, but the problem is that nothing shows up in the `div`, meaning that I either didn't retrieve the data properly or didn't use it right.

Note: I've finally moved on to writing up-to-date code, so I hope no one here comments that somewhere in this code I have outdated code ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $members_array = array();

    while ($member = mysqli_fetch_assoc($members)) {

        $members_array[] = $member;

        //$members_array is array and $member is array so $members_array like $members_array[][];

    };



     <center>
            <h1>Members Directory</h1>
            <div style="width: 20%; height; 75%; border: 3px solid black; margin: auto; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;">

                <?
                      $member_count = count($members_array);

                      for( $i = 0 ; $i < $member_count ; $i++ ){

                          echo $member_array[$i]['Username'];

                          echo "<br />";

                      }

                ?>
            </div>
    </center>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I forgot all about those type of `for` functions!